# Php Cron job in ubuntu 10.10 does not execute for lampp - Help needed

Tags: php, linux, cron, lampp

I need some help with a daily cron job I am trying to schedule under ubuntu 10.10. I have added the job via `crontab -e` and when I do `crontab -l`, it looks ok. Path and naming are fine:

```
58 23 * * * /usr/bin/php -f /home/eem/cars1/cron/cronjob1.php
```

However, the cron does not execute. I have tried to run it manually from gnome scheduler. No success. I tired to run it manually from the console with this command, again without success:

```
/usr/bin/php -f /home/eem/cars1/cron/cronjob1.php
```

My var/log/syslog show that the file is executed but nothing changes in the website on Xampp:

```
May 14 06:27:57 eem-VirtualBox /usr/bin/crontab[31959]: (eem) LIST (eem)
```

This command: `*/5 * * * * echo hello` in `crontab -e` executes and shows in syslog:

```
May 14 05:40:01 eem-VirtualBox CRON[31085]: (eem) CMD (echo hello)
May 14 05:40:01 eem-VirtualBox CRON[31084]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
```

Below some diagnostics:

**Command1**: `ps -C cron`

**Terminal**:

```
PID TTY          TIME CMD
  881 ?        00:00:02 cron
```

**var/log/syslog**:

```
May 14 05:17:01 eem-VirtualBox CRON[31033]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
```

---

**Command2:**: `cat /etc/crontab`

**Terminal:**

```
SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

# m h dom mon dow user  command
17 *    * * *   root    cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
25 6    * * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
47 6    * * 7   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly )
52 6    1 * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly )
#
```

---

**Command3:** `ls /usr/sbin/anacron`

**Terminal:** `/usr/sbin/anacron`

---

**Command4:** `grep CRON /var/log/syslog`

**Terminal:**: This and much more:

> May 14 05:09:01 eem-VirtualBox CRON[30048]: (root) CMD (  [ -x
>   /usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime ] && [ -d /var/lib/php5 ] && find
>   /var/lib/php5/ -depth -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -cmin
>   +$(/usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime) ! -execdir fuser -s {} 2>/dev/null \; -delete) May 14 05:17:01 eem-VirtualBox CRON[31033]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)

Apologies for the long post but after struggling for several days with this I am desperate to find the problem. Hopefully, it will be helpful to other people after that.

Comment: What if you change `php` from `58 23 * * * php /home/eem/cars1/cron/cronjob1.php` with the full path of php? You can get it with `which php`.

Comment: Tried that one as well, nothing happens in the syslog file:

/usr/bin/php /home/eem/cars1/cron/cronjob1.php

Comment: You should split the problem in two pieces: crontab and script. For crontab, do a simple thing like `* * * * * touch /tmp/abcdef` to see if it works. If it does, crontab is working. For the script, you have to make sure your command works alone before adding it into the crontab.

Comment: `* * * * * touch /tmp/abcdef ` works ok. For the script how do you suggest to test if the command works alone? It works fine if I start the php file in browser. Same file also works on the live server when the cron job is scheduled via control panel. Just cannot have it to work on my test server.

Comment: You can paste the command `php /home/eem....` in your command line and see if it works.

Comment: tried that but nothing happens, even in syslog. What does that mean when the crontab works fine?

Comment: It means that the command itself is wrong. Note that crontab is not doing magic, it is just performing a command at specific time. You said before that the command works fine in the browser. Maybe it means that the user who has to run the command is not yours, but `apache` or `http`, that is, the server's user.

Comment: hummm, this was my initial suspicion that it has to do something with the user permissions. do you have any suggestion where to start looking for?

Comment: I would initially give permissions 777 to the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to find out what is wrong with the code. It turned out the ADOdb libraries are not supported on command line.

So I had the PHP files changed and it all works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

I read your comments, you should definitely, get it to run manually before attempting to schedule it.

Get the info from php configuration:

```
<?php
     phpinfo() 
?>
```

To find out installation path `which php`, for the version `php -v`

Finally make sure the script is executable `chmod +x /home/eem/cars1/cron/cronjob1.php`